# export default something() meaning

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I was going through [React Navigation docs](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/tab-based-navigation.html) and I encountered something like this over there:

```
import Ionicons from 'react-native-vector-icons/Ionicons';
import { createBottomTabNavigator } from 'react-navigation';

export default createBottomTabNavigator(
  {
```

Now, I am unable to comprehend what this line does:

```
export default createBottomTabNavigator(
```

I mean it definitely exports something but is it a function?

If yes, then shouldn't it be like:

```
export default function createBottomTabNavigator(
```

or According to ES6 something like this:

```
export default function createBottomTabNavigator = () =>{
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code is equivalent to

```
const MyBottomTabNavigator = createBottomTabNavigator( { /* ... */ });
export default MyBottomTabNavigator;
```

The function is called, an Object is returned. The Object is exported and used elsewhere.

Edit:
More example code in the same vein:

```
const rootOf2 = Math.sqrt(2.0);
export default rootOf2;
```

Comment: Just to confirm, Since I can't see `MyBottomTabNavigator` anywhere, Can I say this to be equivalence of this -> `const createBottomTabNavigator = createBottomTabNavigator( { /* ... */ }); 
export default createBottomTabNavigator;` ?

Comment: @KuchBhi No, not at all. `MyBottomTabNavigator` is an example name I've used; you cannot see it anywhere but right in my example code. It's a constant I have declared and assigned in the first line, then used in the second. I specifically called it "My..." in order to make it obvious that it's not part of some library. Do you not know how constants and variables work?

Answer (score 1):

Answer given by Chris G is correct. I would also like to add that there is the difference between two ways you can export your variables or functions, by export and export default.

Imagine having variable in file `const myVar = 'someValue';`
If you export it from file just with export `export { myVar }` you would have to import it in the file where you would like to use your variable of function like this: `import { myVar } from 'name-of-your-module';`

In other case, where you export it with default `export default myVar`, you can import it without {} - like this: `import myVar from 'name-of-your-module'`

Export default serves to export a single value or to have a fallback value for our module.

Comment: Thanks a lot Lazar though I was already aware about it. 
But Still Thanks :)

Comment: It's edge-casey, but FYI, the use of `export { ... }` doesn't necessarily mean it's not a default. Doing `export { myVar as default };` is also valid.